# Understanding the boto documentation for Elastic Transcoder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to create my own pipe line in Elastic Transcoder. I am using the boto standard function create_pipeline(name, input_bucket, output_bucket, role, notifications).
Can you please tell me the notifications (structure) how it should look? 
So far I have something like this:
create_pipeline('test','test_start', 'test_end',
                     'arn:aws:iam::789823056103:role/Elastic_Transcoder_Default_Role',  ... )

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a dictionary with the 4 keys in the dictionary (I'm going to push a change that updates the structure type with the dict type). So if you don't want notifications, you just specify empty values for the keys:

{'Progressing': '', 'Completed': '', 'Warning': '', 'Error': ''}

Comment: This is the answer I got from James Saryerwinnie